# Deleted the file completely from Machine and git always shows that Changes not staged for commit how to resolve

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted a file that belonged to one of the Git repository from my hard drive and recycle bin now Every time I see git status I run across the statements:

```
**On branch master
    Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    first test.txt
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")**
```

---

If I try removing the file via -
    **git rm first test.txt**
I again get the result as :
**`fatal: pathspec 'first' did not match any files`**

My File is " ***First test.txt*** "
I am a newbie to get and want to resolve this some how!! 
An Explanation to this shall be highly valuable

Comment: To specify the name of something that contains a space (or some other special character) you must enclose the name in quotes, so to ask git to remove a file that contains a space in its name you would issue this command: `git rm "first test.txt"`

Comment: You say **accidentally** deleted a file. Well, do you want to bring back the file or have you changed your mind and *really* want to delete it after all?

Comment: I pressed ctrl+D from my computer as well as from the recycle bin also so there is no scopes of recovering it !! In this case git is showing me the error that file has been deleted and now I couldn't delete in through the git which I actually wanted to practice about..

Answer (score 0):

> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

You need to `Add` and `Commit` the changes.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Delete the file'
$ git push origin HEAD

$ git status
```

---

**Alternate:** If not works, then *reset* your HEAD (undo the delete). Then delete by `git rm`, *Add*, *Commit*, *Push*.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD              # undo/discard the delele/change
$ git rm <file-name>                 # remove the file by git command 
$ git add .                          
$ git commit -m 'Delete the file'
$ git push origin HEAD
```